# Django pass foreign key to the create view

Tags: django, forms, primary-key

I am trying to pass the foreign key to the create view, what would be the best way to do it?

Models:

```
class Building(models.Model):
     # Name of the project
     name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Project ID')
     # The address of the building
     address = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Address')

class Cabinet(Project):
     # The level that kitchen needs to be installed if applicable
     level = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Floor")
     # The building
     building = models.ForeignKey(Building)
```

url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
           ...
           # url to add new cabinet
           url(r'^cabinet/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', CabinetCreate.as_view(), name='new_cabinet'),
           ...
```

view:

```
class CabinetCreate(generic.CreateView):
   model = Cabinet
   form_class = UpdateCabinetForm
   template_name = "projects/cabinetEdit.html"

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      self.object = None
      form_class = self.get_form_class()
      form = self.get_form(form_class)
      return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      self.object = None
      form_class = self.get_form_class()
      form = self.get_form(form_class)
      if form.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
```

template:

I pass the building id to the create view.

```
 ...
 <a href="{% url 'projectmonitor:new_cabinet' building.id %}" class="left-link">Add New Cabinet</a>
 ...
```

When the new cabinet is created, the building object is already existed, there is a "Save" button which triggers a POST request on the CabinetCreate view template, but every time when I save the new cabinet object, it shows:

```
Column 'building_id' cannot be null
```

Does anyone have any idea how do I assign the building or building id before I save the cabinet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the building foreign key before saving the object...

```
if form.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        # self.object.building = BUILDING OBJECT
        self.object.save()
```